# Showing $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} K \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensors

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - 2)$.
I want to show that $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} K \cong \mathbb{R}^2$.
Then $\mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} K \cong \mathbb{R} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} 
\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 - 2) \cong  \mathbb{R}[x]/(x-\sqrt2)(x+ \sqrt2)
\cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x - \sqrt2) \times \mathbb{R}[x]/(x + \sqrt2)$ 
by the Chinese remainder theorem of modules.

Now this is where I am confused. Is this then isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$? I know they are isomorphic as rings, but I'm not sure about as $\mathbb{R}$-modules since I know two simple modules are only isomorphic if they have the same annihilator. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathbb R$ is a field, an $\mathbb R$-module is exactly the same thing as a vector space over $\mathbb R$. The only isomorphism invariant of a vector space over a field is its dimension over that field. So all you have to prove is that $\mathbb R \otimes_{\mathbb Q} K$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb R$. And this should be a simple consequence of the fact that $K$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Having said that, there's a question of what "kind" of isomorphism the problem asks for. But $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$ does not ordinarily come equipped with any multiplication, it's only structure is really just its bare vector space structure over $\mathbb R$. So I think that the "ring" structure is not relevant to this question, although since I cannot see the original problem this is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: oh right! Thank you!

Comment: The problem does not say what kind of isomorphism which was what was confusing me. Is it OK to apply the Chinese remainder theorem then if we are viewing the tensor product as a vector space?

Answer (score 5):

The isomorphism $\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2-2)$ is $(a,b) \to a \frac{x-\sqrt{2}}{-2 \sqrt{2}} + b\frac{x+\sqrt{2}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$

and the isomorphism $ \Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2-2)\to \Bbb{R} \otimes_{\Bbb{Q}}\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$ is $c+dx \to c \otimes_{\Bbb{Q}} 1 + d  \otimes_{\Bbb{Q}} x$